# Mixed Recessed LED Lights Not Working

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, led

I purchased a home that has recessed lighting throughout. They are the LED lights that clip into a standard light bulb screw-in socket. They all point straight down and I wanted to purchase some that gimbal to highlight some artwork.

All of the existing lights are 10w 120v/60hz.

I purchased a 15w gimballed light and tested it in a bedroom and it worked fine.

However, when I installed it in the main room where the artwork is, it would not turn on. I tested two different fixtures with the same result. I then tested the new light in the kitchen and it worked fine in there.

The main room has a total of 12 lights where the other rooms I tested only have 4. This is the only difference that I could think of between the two rooms.

I ordered a 10w gimbaled light to test but it just seems strange to me that this is the problem.

Anything else I haven't though of?

Comment: Tell us about the dimmer. ..

Comment: Exactly my thoughts. There's probably a dimmer that won't do LED, or it does do LED but is incompatible with these lights

Comment: No dimmer - just one switch. All of the lights (old and new) are dimmer compatible though

Comment: Edit: I lied - I found a second switch and it did have a dimmer (dimmed all the way down). New light turns on now - I wonder why all the existing lights aren't impacted...

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add this as an answer to your question, so that someone else with the same problem may find it? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments above indicated, the problem was a dimmer switch that I didn't know existed.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Would you accept it as the correct answer? And, bonus points if you can add a bit more detail.